# Can Cat 5 cables be differentiated mid-run?

Tags: networking, cat5

My house has two Cat 5 cables that go through my garage from my office to some bedrooms. One of the cables isn't in use, and I'd like to repurpose it for a drop in the garage. Is there a way to tell which cable is the inactive one without cutting it? The cables are identical and, of course, unlabeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use a tone generator to work out which of the cables in the garage has the unused end in your office.

Comment: Thanks, this has made me realize that I misunderstood the full function of a toner, so I've done further research and it looks like it's probably what I need.